# Sum of First 1000 primes not correct? what's wrong?

Tags: java, algorithm, primes

Here is what I have

```
public class SumOfPrimes {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long sum = 0;
        for (int i = 2; i <= 1000; i++) {
            if (isPrime(i)) {
                sum += i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }

    private static boolean isPrime(final int number) {
        for (int i = 2; i * i <= number; i++) {
            if (number % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

What I get is

```
76127
```

However the correct answer is

```
3682913
```

Reference: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+first+1000+prime+numbers&x=0&y=0

I am not able to spot bug in my code, any help here?

Comment: "The sum of the first 1000 primes" is not the same as ["the sum of all primes which are <= 1000"](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+primes+%3C%3D+1000)

Comment: You can make this a little more efficient by starting sum on 2, i on 3, and returning false in isPrime for anything that is a multiple of 2. Then you can start isPrime's i on 3, and increment by 2 in each loop, thereby checking only odd numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I completely misunderstood the question. The following worked out to be fine

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        long sum = 0;
        int count = 0;
        int number = 2;
        while (count < 1000) {
            if (isPrime(number)) {
                sum += number;
                count++;
            }
            number++;
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Its correct **as indicated by Blorgbeard "The sum of the first 1000 primes" is not the same as "the sum of all primes which are <= 1000"**.

**In your case the main is calculating sum of first 168 prime numbers.**

You need to **rewrite the main as following to get the sum of first 1000 prime numbers**:

```
public static void main(String args[]){

    int number = 2;
    int count = 0;
    long sum = 0;
    while(count < 1000){
        if(isPrime(number)){
            sum += number;
            count++;
        }
        number++;
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Output:

```
3682913
```

Comment: Er, and how is this different from OP's own answer? looks like a copy-paste to me...

Answer (score 1):

Your program is correct, I just tested it in Python.

```
from math import *

def testPrime(num): #Takes a number as an argument
if num < 2:
    return False
if (num == 2):
    return True
else:
    for aNum in range(2, num):
        if (int)(num % aNum == 0):
            return False

    return True

# Allow user to enter input



c = 1
sum = 0
sumPrimes = 0
while (c < 100):
    if (testPrime(c)):

        print(c)
        sum = sum + log(c)
        sumPrimes = sumPrimes + c

   c = c + 1
```

print("Sum of log quotient:", sum/c)
print(sumPrimes)

A good way to test your program is to manually add up a set of the first few primes (2, 3, 5). The answer to this is easy, input it into your program and examine the output.

Here is my output:

```
2
3
5
7
11
13
17
19
23
29
31
37
41
43
47
53
59
61
67
71
73
79
83
89
97
Sum of log quotient: 0.8372839039906392
1060
```

The ratio of the prime numbers to their log quotient should approach 1, but should never exceed it (An interesting tidbit).

Answer (score 0):

Actually you did the program for finding the sum of prime numbers up to 1000 and it is 76127 and the sum of first 1000 natural numbers is 3682913.

**Sum of first 1000 natural numbers**

```
int n=2,count=0;
long int sum=0;
while(count<1000){
    if(isPrime(n)){ 
        sum+=n;
        count++;
    }
    n++;
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: This code doesn't even compile. In Java, boolean values can not be compared with numbers - in other words, this is invalid code: `isPrime(n)==1`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int prime(int no,int lim)
{
    int i=2,flag=0;
    for(;i<=lim;i++)
    {
        if(no%i==0)
        {   
            flag=1;     
        }
    }
    return flag ;
}

int main()
{
    int i=4,count=2,j,k,l,n=4;
    double sum=5.0;

    for(;count<=1000;)
    {   
        j=sqrt(i);
        k=prime(i,j);
        if(k==0)
        {
            //printf("\n%d",i);
            sum+=(double)i;
            //for(l=0;l<100000;l++);//just to reduce speed of the program

            count++;
        }
    i++;

}
printf("\n%f",sum);
        return 0;   
}
```